# Implementing a multikey index's uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have three models Therapist, Patient, and Report.

```
therapist.rb
has_many  :reports

patient.rb
has_many :reports

report.rb
belongs_to  :therapist
belongs_to  :patient
```

when I created the report model my migration looked like this
XXXXX_create_reports.rb

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.integer :therapist_id
      t.integer :patient_id
      t.datetime :performed_on
      t.integer :duration
      t.datetime :signed_on

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :reports, [:therapist_id, :patient_id, :performed_on], unique:true
    add_index :reports, [:patient_id, :performed_on]
    add_index :reports, :performed_on
  end
end
```

but when I went to test the uniquess like so.

```
def setup
    @tpist   = therapists(:bill)
    @patient  = patients(:ted)
    @report = Report.new(therapist_id: @tpist.id,
                          patient_id:   @patient.id,
                          performed_on: Faker::Date.backward(1.day))
end

test "report should be unique" do
    duplicate_report = @report.dup
    @report.save
    assert_not duplicate_report.valid?
  end
```

The test fails meaning that the report was saved to the db. I got a little confused reading all the questions and documentation about multiple key indexes. Am I not implementing the multiple key index and uniqueness correctly?

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. am I not allowed to have a column in my table that is the same as another model that it has an association with? I was just reading the association basics page and they had in their migration a example create_table :orders do |t|
      t.belongs_to :customer, index: true is that what i should be doing and if so how do i implement uniqueness on the three fields?

Comment: what is your Faker::Date.backward(1.day)) returning?

Comment: That just returns a datetime i replaced it with Time.now it didn't make a difference. I think it has to do with the migration switching the therapist_id with a refrences :therapist, foreign_key:true?

Comment: Remove the extra "  add_index :reports, [:patient_id, :performed_on]  " and 
 "   add_index :reports, :performed_on  ". I guess the problem can be there.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) Rails doesn't provide **Composite Primary Keys** out of the box.

A way of overcoming that is by using a gem such as [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys).

Comment: Thank You. I was not familiar with composite Primary keys. From reading the documentation It seems like the only place this index is declared is in the model associations. I could not find an example of a migration file so do I just leave the indexes off the table? If so how would I enforce uniqueness of that three value key?